# Drawing a bufircation diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$\dot x=x(\mu+x-2)(\mu+2x-x^2)$

The first thing I did was to check the fixed points in the $(\mu,x)$-plane:

$x=0$

$x=2-\mu$ (saddle node at 0 when $\mu$)

$x_{1,2}=1+-\sqrt{\mu+1}$ (no fixed point for $\mu<1$)

Did I specified the type for the bufircation points correctly?

How does the bifurcation diagram now looks like? I do not know how to draw them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would look at the qualitative behavior for various values of $\mu$ and validate your critical points.

Here are four cases for $\mu =-2, -1, 0 , +1$. Look for the critical points and see what happens at each. You should also learn to draw these by hand as you know the derivative information, you know the critical points and you can choose several values between regions and determine direction. Look at what happens in each and make sure it matches your analysis (which is correct).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! Very nice collection here! +1

Comment: I made a mistake to do this but my friend did it well :+)

Comment: @B.S.: Thank you my friend. I however really liked that animated phase portrait and now have to figure out how to create those too. Regards